# Top words aggregation for each country

Tags: mongodb

Our dataset has the following structure:

```
{
  'country': 'United States',
  'text': 'twitter text string...'
},
{
  'country': 'Australia',
  'text': 'a different twitter text string...'
}
...
```

It includes data from most countries. There are about 1.5 million entries currently. Our goal is to use an aggregation to get the most used words in the text field for each country. Using a combination of $project, $group, $split, $unwind, $nin (for stop words), and $sort, we've managed to get close. It gives us the counts for each word, separated by country, which we can then sort to get the top words. However, I'm trying to figure out how to get it to only give the top N words for each country. So basically calculate the word counts for each country, sort, then return only the top N for each country.

I'm still new to MongoDB queries. I'm not necessarily looking for a complete solution, but I'm wondering what query parameters and accumulators I should be looking at to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
           {  
              $project:{  
                 country:1,
                 words:{  
                    $split:[ "$text", " " ]
                 }
              }
           },
           {  
              $unwind:"$words"
           },
           {  
              $group:{  
                 _id:{  
                    country:"$country",
                    word:"$words"
                 },
                 count:{  
                    $sum:1
                 }
              }
           },
           {  
              $match:{  
                 "_id.word":{  
                    $nin:[ "a" ]
                 }
              }
           },
           {  
              $sort:{  
                 count:-1
              }
           },
           {  
              $group:{  
                 _id:"$_id.country",
                 top_words:{  
                    $push:"$_id.word"
                 }
              }
           },
           {  
              $project:{  
                 country:1,
                 top_words:{  
                    $slice:[ "$top_words", 2 ]
                 }
              }
           }
        ])
```

1. split the text on white space in a **`$project`** stage
2. unwind the resulting array
3. group by `country` and `words` to get the count of each word for each country
4. filter out stop words in a **`$match`** stage
5. sort on `count`
6. group documents by `country` and push each word in an array named `top_words`
7. slice the array to get the top N words (here the top 2)

Comment: This worked beautifully; thank you. $push was the key thing I was missing. One problem I'm stilling having is with the sort. It's giving me an error that it's trying to use too much memory because the list of distinct words is too large apparently. My solution for now was to filter out anything with less than a count of 10. Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: @anderspitman you may try to add `allowDiskUse: true` in the options of the query to avoid memory error

Comment: Wouldn't that significantly slow down the query? Mongo is already allocating more than 20GB of memory on my system. What's it doing with it if not allowing it for queries?

Comment: @anderspitman actually, each stage in mongodb aggregation can use up to  100MB of RAM. If the stage use more, you'll need to allow disk use to enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/ for details